# Is it OK to use redundant/nested withContext calls?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a personal project written in Kotlin, and I developed a habit of using `withContext(...)` very generously. I tend to use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` when calling anything that could possibly be related to I/O.

For example:

```kotlin
suspend fun getSomethingFromDatabase(db: AppDatabase) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    return // ...
}

suspend fun doSomethingWithDatabaseItem(db: AppDatabase) {
    val item = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        getSomethingFromDatabase(db)
    }
    // ...
}
```

You can see a redundant `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` in the second function. I'm being extra cautious here, because I might not know/remember if `getSomethingFromDatabase` switches to an appropriate context or not. Does this impact performance? Is this bad? What's the idiomatic way of dealing with `Dispatchers`?

Note: I know that it's perfectly fine to switch between different contexts this way, but this question is specifically about using *the same context*.

Comment: I would log something in `getSomethingFromDatabase` method and then again something in `doSomethingWithDatabaseItem` method after the `withContext` call. Then you can check the thread name. If it is the same (which I assume will be the case) I would say it is ok to do that, but I am in a grey area on this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need `withContext` for anything besides calling code that demands a specific context. Therefore `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` should only be used when you're working with UI functions that require the main thread. And you should only use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` when calling **blocking** IO related code.

A proper suspend function does not block ([see **Suspending convention** section here](https://elizarov.medium.com/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761)), and therefore, you should *never* have to specify a dispatcher to call a suspend function.

Exceptions:

- You're working with someone else's code or API and they are using suspend functions incorrectly.
- There isn't really a convention about functions that require the main thread. They aren't blocking but could break if not called on Dispatchers.Main. IMO, if it's a public function, then internalize any necessary `withContext` to encapsulate rather than exposing a failure opportunity.
- Maybe in private functions you want to optimize something and avoid unnecessary dispatcher switching, so you might carefully structure your code accordingly. It's hard for me to imagine a case where this isn't a silly micro-optimization though--if you're switching contexts within some functions (by calling `suspend` functions within `suspend` functions), you aren't saving much by avoiding switching contexts here and there. I prefer to solve problems at the source. The benefits of encapsulation aren't just for classes, but also for individual functions.

I don't know what your AppDatabase class is, but if it is sensibly designed, it will expose suspend functions instead of blocking functions, so you should not need `withContext` to retrieve values from it. But if it does expose blocking functions for retrieving items, then the code of your first function is correct.

And your second function definitely doesn't need `withContext` because it's simply using it to call something that I can see is a suspend function.

As for whether it's OK to use redundant context switching...it doesn't hurt anything besides possibly wasting a tiny bit of time and memory context switching and allocating lambdas for no reason. And it makes your code less readable.

Comment: I use Android room for my database, which generates methods automatically for me. I marked its methods as `suspend` but I don't know if they switch to the right context. The auto-generated Java code is very hard to read, and I don't trust it.

Comment: Any Room functions marked `suspend` actually suspend so they use appropriate context under the hood (don't block). At least, I trust that they wouldn't offer the ability to mark those functions as `suspend` for no reason whatsoever.

Comment: Can confirm, Room functions marked with `suspend` switch to the right context. I think I can make my code much cleaner now, thanks!